# Bat file to replace all occurrences of a character in a filename with another

Tags: regex, batch-file, full-text-search, filenames

I need to do this on a list of a few thousand filenames such that the files are renamed with the replaced characters.  The intent is to allow the following script to run on ALL names

The problem is names with the "&" sign.

I am using this script to locate all the filenames on a list containing several thousand names which has to be run against multiple folders full of the files to find just the ones on the list.  If found I can either copy or move the file onto a flash-drive.

The script is working flawlessly except for names containing the "&". Unfortunately quite a few do.  Other than finding a way to escape the & during the search, I could replace it with the any unique word or character long enough to run the search and reversing this after the files are found.

The initial script is like this:

```
set list=C:\ALIST.txt
pushd %source%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%list%) do (echo.%%a && call :FindIt "%%~a")
goto :End

:FindIt
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%b in (`dir /b /s /a-d-s-h "%~1"`) do (call :DoIt "%%~dpb" "%~1")
goto :EOF

:DoIt
set str=%~1
set str=%str:~0,-1%
set file=%~2
rem NOTE: ADD /MOV at end of next line  to move instead of COPY
robocopy "%str%" "%dest%" "%file%" 
goto :EOF

:End
popd
```

This was written by a good friend and I am not taking credit for his work.
I looked everywhere to find a way to do this and his script was a Godsend that brought me 95% of the way to an end.  The only problem with it is getting it to accept names with the "&" sign or short for that finding a way to replace the "&" sign temporarily long enough to run the script.

Any ideas or alternatives appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be missing quotes

```
set "str=%~1"
set "str=%str:~0,-1%"
set "file=%~2"
```

But, without full knowledge of how/why this is done this way (probably it should be shorter), the full code can be written as

```dos
pushd %source% && (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%list%) do (
        echo(%%a
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ('
            dir /b /s /a-d-s-h "%%~a"
        ') do robocopy "%%~dpb\." "%dest%" "%%~a"
    )
    popd
)
```

without `call` and without substring operations.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work nicely though I can't vouch for spaces and special characters. Place this in a file called **This.that.and.the.other.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set src=%~n0
set "tgt=%src:.=!p! " & call set "tgt=!tgt!%"
@echo %src%
@echo %tgt%
endlocal
```